# Printing multiple variables inside quotes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, string-formatting

I am trying to print multiple variables in a print statement but I want all the variables to be printed in double quotes

While using normal formatting I am able to get it printed without the double quotes (%s) but unable to get it printed inside the double quotes while using the statement as below

```
print "Hostname='"%s"' IP='"%s"' tags='"%s"'"%(name,value["ip"],tags)
```

Comment: Switch to Python 3 (latest) and explore cool string formatting options.

Comment: You don't even need to switch to Python 3 (though you should, the [clock is ticking](https://pythonclock.org)) for most of the formatting options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enclose the entire string with single quotes (`'`) and each `%s` with double quotes (`"`):

```
print 'Hostname="%s" IP="%s" tags="%s"' % (name, value["ip"], tags)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either go with [MrGeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696407/1622937) or you can simply escape the double quotes:

```
print "Hostname=\"%s\" IP=\"%s\" tags=\"%s\"" % (name, value["ip"], tags)
```

Either way will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use str.format()

```
print ('Hostname="{}" IP="{}" tags="{}"' .format(name,value["ip"],tags) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape with `\` or use single quotes and qouble inside. See tutorial here:

http://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/tutorial7.html

```
>>> print "\"hello\""  
"hello"  
>>> print '"\\" is the backslash'   # Try with "\" instead of "\\"  
"\" is the backslash
```